# How to determine if a function is a test function?

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization

My textbook states that $\phi(x)$ is a test function, and then states that $\phi(ax+b)$ (where $a > 0$ and $b$ is a real number), $f(x)\phi(x)$ where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary smooth function, and $\phi^{(k)}(x)$ where $k$ is a natural number are also test functions.

How do I know this is true? I am a little confused with the actual definition of a test function as well. My textbook says:

A map $\phi : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ is a test function if it is smooth (i.e. infinitely differentiable) and if there exists $X$ such that $\phi(x) = 0$ when $|x| > X$.

Comment: Well, if $\Phi(x)$ is a test function then it is smooth.  Doesn't it follow that $\Phi(x)^n$ is also smooth? And if f(x) is a smooth function, then $f(x)\Phi(x)$ is also smooth.  $0^n= 0$ and any number times 0 is 0.

Comment: Intuitively, I understand it, but I just don't get any of the math involved. For example, my professor stated that a test function means that $\phi$ exists on [0,1], and used that to prove whether something is a test function

Comment: "Means that" **what**?  Didn't you give the definition of "test function"?  It's definition is the only thing any word *can* mean!

Comment: Yes, I also wasn't sure what he said that meant. I got this definition out of the textbook because what he said was confusing. I just want to mathematically derive that the first three functions are test functions, and I am not sure how to do that with the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why wouldn't the scaled and translated versions of $\phi$ be also infinitely differentiable?
If $\phi$ is a test function then it is infinitely differentiable.
$\phi(ax + b)$ is also infinitely differentiable (derive!):
$$\phi'(ax+b)a$$
$$\phi''(ax+b)a^2$$
$$\phi^{(n)}(ax+b) = a^n \phi^{(n)}(ax+b) $$